# How to debug the Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have built a new "Hello World" plugin for Jenkins and I was able to upload it onto Jenkins and it works successfully. I am now trying to make change to the plugin and debug it on Jenkins.

Note:
My Jenkins is deployed in my local tomcat, i build the **hpi** file and copy it to jenkins plugins folder, it works.

Now i want to ask how can i debug my plugin code? Suggestions with any IDE is welcome.
I also have questions about:

1. do i need to create a project for jenkins source in my IDE and develop my plugin base on it?
   Currently i only create a project for the plugin, build a hpi file and put it to Jenkins.
   I am not sure if this step is correct.
   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I imagine you ran

```
mvn package
```

to create your package

To debug you can do

```
mvnDebug hpi:run
```

and this will copy all the dependencies down (rather than in your jenkins install) and run it in place

If you are using an IDE then this can be done from within it.

More help can be found in the [plugin tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, actually i mvnDebug like you mentioned before, there comes out an error:Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp optioFinally i solved this question by following the tutorialns. Finally i solved this issue by follwing the tutorial and using intelliJ IDE. I have already vote your answer up.

Answer (score 6):

Follow the [tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial) to set MAVEN_OPTS, and using IntelliJ to add a Jetty Server to point the port to it.

execute from cmd:

```
mvn clean
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n
mvn hpi:run
```

add a debug local Jetty Server from intelliJ and point it to port 8000 (port number is specified in above cmd)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case of IntelliJ IDEA the easiest way is to use maven's Run/Debug configuration.
Just add `hpi:run` in "Command line" filed and start Debug as usual.
When the console says that your "Jenkins is fully up and running", open a browser and go to http://localhost:8080/jenkins/ and your code will stopped at break point (if any).